# Video File uploader

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, ftp

We are developing a video file upload feature in a php website. We need to upload files upto at least 100MB. We are using some flash upload tools which shows progress bars.

When we try, even 10 MB files are itself taking lot of time and progress bar seem to end very fast and we have to wait long time to finish uploading. Is there any good progress bar plugins for large file uploads

Also can we use any other file upload methods other than http upload?

Is it possible to upload file using FTP for video file uploads. I have seen a few samples but nothing seem to working..

Comment: While saying FTP, what is in your mind? Create separate FTP accounts for each user and let them connect with any FTP program to upload? This is just going to push ppl away. More job you will ask them to do more users you will lose who are willing to share some stuff.

Comment: @Pixeler.. No... I am thinking of a solution where the php script will connect to our server using ftp and upload this file to our server. Is it possible?

Comment: Leaving aside the grammar, "Is there any good progress bar plugins for large file uploads" - You do not seem able to discriminate between the underlying protocol and its implementation and the user interface, which makes me wonder whether you will understand any answer given here. What have you done to investigate why your current solution fails to meet your requirements?

Comment: @symcbean. I think you did not understand my question. Anyway I am getting answers from others.. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, if you wish to go down the PHP route then take a look http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/.

else, you can try the JAVA applet route and a good place to start would be with http://jupload.sourceforge.net/

I think in this case i would use the Java Applet.

Answer (score 0):

FTP can be more tricky for the user than a plain html upload form, but would be the preferred way to upload in my opinion (robust protocol, resume support etc.)

For a nice html upload form, you could have a look at [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), which offers a wide variety of options for client side plugins. It supports graceful degradation, and in the case of html5 file uploads support, it also supports chunking the upload.